# How do get the additional data after Mongo Group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following data in mongoDb, where I am storing user activities. Where timestamp is the time when the record was created.

I want what is the most recent activity by every user.

```
{ user: "A", activity : "act1" , date: timestamp}
{ user: "B", activity : "act3" , date: timestamp}
{ user: "C", activity : "act2" , date: timestamp}
{ user: "A", activity : "act2" , date: timestamp}
{ user: "B", activity : "act3" , date: timestamp}
{ user: "C", activity : "act1" , date: timestamp}
```

Grouping using

```
db.aggregate({
  [  
     $group: {
       _id: "$user",
       latest_activity_time: {$max: "$date"},
     }
  }])
```

gives me only The most recent activity time, I am not able to get the most recent activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the incumbent documents in the pipeline first using the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline operator then use either **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** accumulator operators in your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step, depending on the previous sort direction:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$sort": { "date": -1 } }, // or order by date ascending { "$sort": { "date": 1 } }
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user",
            "latest_activity": { "$first": "$activity" }, // if ordered by date ascending "latest_activity": { "$last": "$activity" }
            "latest_activity_time": { "$first": "$date" } // if ordered by date ascending "latest_activity_time": { "$last": "$date" }
        }
    }
];

Model.aggregate(pipeline)
     .exec(function (err, result){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
     });
```